# Concatenating PHP mail header with dynamic email from post

Tags: php

I am trying to setup a dynamic email address in PHP mail function header and instead of having this

```
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

I have changed it to this:

```
$uemail = $_POST['uemail'];
//...
$headers .= 'From: <'.$uemail.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$uemail. "\r\n";
```

The email is not sending. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the error message from the php error log

Comment: It seems you are adding a second "From:" field. Why? For the format of these fields see here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322